# Mysql Count()

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Перед запуском сайта решил проконсультироваться со знающими людьми.
Так вот, имеется страница, на которой выводится количество сообщений, которые писал пользователь. 
Хотелось бы узнать, сильно ли будет грузить сервер, если постоянно считать количество записей, которые оставил определенный пользователь. Выборка идет по id.

Есть варианты:

1. Считать каждый раз количество записей и кешировать число memCached, например на 2 мин.
2. Заносить число сообщений в отдельное поле с записью о данных пользователя.

Если использовать второй метод, то это очень не удобно, при каждом добавление и удаление менять число. Так же число может быть ошибочным. Если будет ошибочным, то нужно как-то его восстанавливать.

Первый метод удобнее, но меня смущает то, будет ли нагрузка на сервер?
В качестве небольшого уменьшения запросов кешировать число.
Допустим, если таблица будет состоять из 10 000 записей до 50 000 записей?

Как лучше всего работать в данной ситуации? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count работает очень быстро. Долго работает выборка записей, поэтому если выборка будет по индексу, а выводить надо для каждого пользователя только его сообщения - беспокоиться нечего. Если же(например, как на форумах) надо выводить количество сообщений для всех пользователей в табличку, имеет смысл все-таки завести в таблице, скажем, users_parameters дополнительное поле. Обновление поля - по добавлении/удалении сообщения(это всяко реже, чем чтение!). Для исключения ошибок можно раз в N часов, либо по запросу пользователя/администратора делать ресинхронизацию и пересчет.

P.S. что за таблица из 50000 записями? Если это таблица пользователей, однозначно второй способ. Если таблица сообщений - спокойно можно использовать первый: тормозить не будет, даже если делать выборку по ТЕКСТОВОМУ полю nickname.

Comment: Спасибо. Если count() быстрый, то лучше использовать его и использовать memcached. Как только пользователь добавит новое сообщение, то число из кеша удалиться и заново посчитается и занесется в кеш. Думаю так удобнее. 50 К записей - это записи с сообщениями, что-то вроде форума. =)

Answer (score 0):

Лучшего всего второй вариант, при изменении кол-ва постов перечитывать, но ... поскольку речь идет уже о готовом сайте - лучше кэшировать.

Сам по себе запрос не шибко тяжелый, но смысл каждый раз пересчитывать все посты, юзер ведь не постоянно их пишет.